# PHP bad mail headers

Tags: php, email, html-email, phpmailer, email-headers

I want to send an email via the `mail()` function.

`mail($to,$subject,$message)` works fine.

But using `mail($to,$subject,$message,$header)` doesn't work.
The header is:

```
Date: Tue, 2 Jul 2013 15:01:49 +0200 +0200
Return-Path: noreply@myhost.com
From: "noreply@myhost.com"
Message-ID:
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.4 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

What is wrong with my headers?
FYI, the headers are generated by PHPMailer.
The code I use to send it is:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $from;
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  Error message? Nothing sent? Help us to help you.

Comment: Everything seems to work fine, except I don't receive an email. Thats the weird thing.

Comment: have you got access to the mailserver and logs?`have a look in the logs if mail is reveived at all

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use another header?
I use

```
$header = "From: Me@anything.de \n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1; type=\"text/html\" \n"; 
mail($email,$betreff,$mailbody,$header)
```

and it works fine.

Comment: This fixed it for me using XAMPP PHP to "Test Mail Server Tool".

Answer (score 0):

You need a mail server, that you may not have on your dev environment.
mail() and PHPMailer simply hand over your e-mail to a mail server, which will then proceed to actually send it to it's destination.

If you don't have a mail server available, no matter how good your code is, it simply won't do anything. Check for any return codes or exceptions that you may be missing (I'm not sure how PHPMailer indicates something went wrong, mail() does it by return code),

I never really used PHPMailer, but it seems to me that you're not setting an external server to relay the message, which means PHPMailer will default to the local machine.

A mail server isn't something you just install and configure in a couple of minutes, which I believe your local machine doesn't have.

So, here's what I think is happening:
1) You didn't set an external server, PHPMailer defaults to the local server.
2) You don't have a local mail server, which makes PHPMailer fail.
3) You're missing/ignoring $mail->Send()'s return code / thrown exception, which should tell you something went wrong.

Comment: Hi, as I told in the description, just `mail()` without headers works fine because I do have a local mail server. And for the return code of the Send() function: it doesn't show an error.